# minimizing sum of reciprocal via socp

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Given $x_1$, $x_2$,..., $x_n$, with $x_i>0 \forall i \in[1,n]$

I would like to minimize via SOCP the following cost function

$$J = ||\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{\alpha_i}{x_i}}-K||$$, with $K>0$ and $\alpha_i$ given positive constants.

Any suggestion about how to formulate it? The problem should in general always have a solution, because for $x_i\rightarrow 0$ J can become very large, and for $x_i\rightarrow\infty$ the sum will tend to 0. It's just I don't see whether it can be properly cast in SOCP form...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just let $x_i = \alpha_i / K$ for each $i$? When you do so, $J = 0$, which is clearly a minimum. I know this doesn't use SOCP (partly because I have no idea what that is), but it does give a solution.

By the way, as $x_i \to \infty$, $J$ doesn't tend towards 0; it tends towards $Kn$.

**Post-comment addition**

It turns out that the thing to be minimized is 
$$
J = \| K - \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\alpha_i}{x_i} \|,
$$
which wasn't clear (to me) from the initial formulation.

Even so, that too has got an easy solution: 
$$
x_i = \frac{\alpha_i n}{K}
$$
for every $i$; then each term in the sum is 
$$
\frac{\alpha_i}{x_i} =  
\frac{\alpha_i}{\frac{\alpha_i n}{K}} =  
\frac{\alpha_i K}{{\alpha_i n}} = \frac{K}{n} 
$$
so that the sum is exactly $K$, and hence $J = 0$.

**Further post-comment additions**

An SOCP problem is (according to Wikipedia) one in the following form:

Minimize 
$$
{\displaystyle \ f^{T}x\ }
$$
subject to
$$
{\displaystyle \lVert A_{i}x+b_{i}\rVert _{2}\leq c_{i}^{T}x+d_{i}}
\quad i=1,\dots ,m
$$
and
$$
{\displaystyle Fx=g\ } 
$$

OK. I'll formulate your problem that way.

Minimize

$$
0^T x
$$
subject to  no norm conditions (i.e., $m = 0$ in this problem), and one linear condition, namely 
$$
Fx = g
$$
where $F$ is the identity matrix, and $g_i = \frac{\alpha_i n}{K}.
$$

That's an SOCP formulation of a problem completely equivalent to the one you posed. And it happens to be particularly easy to solve, because the solution's in the very last constraint.

Comment: Hi John, I forgot to mention that K is always positive, so we have to exclude the case $K=0$.  For the condition $x_i \rightarrow 0$ I meant that the sum can give any value between 0 and $\infty$, so for a given K there exists always a solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "$J = 0$" rather than $K = 0$; I've edited accordingly. You second sentence makes no sense to me. But assuming it really is $J$ that you want to minimize, I've found a set of $x$s at which it takes on its minimum, so you're done.  If it's *not* $J$ that you want to minimize, you need to rewrite your question.

Comment: Hi John, K is not in the sum. It is counted only once, thanks!

Comment: See post-comment additions.

Comment: Hi John, thanks a lot. However I'm looking for a SOCP formulation of this problem, as I have further conditions to add on the $x_i$ terms. Nevertheless, your idea is nice, but it adds a distortion to my original question.

Comment: See my update for an exact answer to the exact question you asked (which is essentially identical to the answer I gave, but formulated in SOCP terms).  
If you have some other problem you *actually* want to solve, why not ask about it rather than sending folks on a wild goose chase?

Comment: I posted only that part as I started to code SOCP two days ago, and some conditions I need to pose are still on the way. I tried to code it as hyperbolic conic constraints, but it doesn't look fully right. What I needed was the SOCP formulation of the stuff above. I can then add my further conditions as soon as I formulate them, and that's why I was looking for help by some convex optimization expert here on the website. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you go understand your problem clearly enough that you can formulate it so that a correct solution given here will actually help you.